# nginx reverse to all pages

Tags: nginx, web, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have the following configuration that works for only 1 page:

```
  location /mypage.html/ {
    proxy_pass http://${remote_server}/;
    }
```

When I am trying to navigate to other pages on the remote server, I get page not found.
Is there any way to keep the reverse proxy open for all pages on the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

This will match everything, technically everything that starts `/`, and route the same request to your remote server:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://${remote_server}/;
}
```